# L is a linear operator defined as $L:\Bbb{R}^{2×2} \to \Bbb{R}^{2×2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L$ a linear operator defined as $$L:\Bbb{R}^{2×2} \to \Bbb{R}^{2×2}$$
$L(A)=A+A^t$. Find the matrix representation by the standard base of $\Bbb{R}^{2×2}$

Comment: I found $[L]_B= $$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\ 0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&2
\end{array}
\right)
$

Comment: Looks good to me. Just be sure to explicitly state the *ordered* basis you used to construct $[L]_B$